# How to create dropdown in Swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was trying to create a dropdown in Swift UI. Most of the article suggested to use overlay to create the same. Tried some sample code below, However the when drop down comes up it does come in below the next content.[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnTxU.png), How to make this look like normal dropdown? I observed it happens when we add HStack, without that it comes top of the other view, which is expected, But when I try to add HStack its coming behind the UI.  I want the dropdown to look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVi64.png)

```
 import SwiftUI

struct DropdownOption: Hashable {
    let key: String
    let value: String
    
    public static func == (lhs: DropdownOption, rhs: DropdownOption) -> Bool {
        return lhs.key == rhs.key
    }
}

struct DropdownRow: View {
    var option: DropdownOption
    var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if let onOptionSelected = self.onOptionSelected {
                onOptionSelected(self.option)
            }
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text(self.option.value)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
    }
}

struct Dropdown: View {
    var options: [DropdownOption]
    var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(self.options, id: \.self) { option in
                    DropdownRow(option: option, onOptionSelected: self.onOptionSelected)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minHeight: CGFloat(options.count) * 30, maxHeight: 250)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
}

struct DropdownSelector: View {
    @State private var shouldShowDropdown = false
    @State private var selectedOption: DropdownOption? = nil
    var placeholder: String
    var options: [DropdownOption]
    var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
    private let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 45
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.shouldShowDropdown.toggle()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text(selectedOption == nil ? placeholder : selectedOption!.value)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedOption == nil ? Color.gray: Color.black)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: self.shouldShowDropdown ? "arrowtriangle.up.fill" : "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 9, height: 5)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 9, weight: .medium))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .frame(width: .infinity, height: self.buttonHeight)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                Image("top-image")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .scaledToFit()
                if self.shouldShowDropdown {
                    Spacer(minLength: buttonHeight + 10)
                    Dropdown(options: self.options, onOptionSelected: { option in
                        shouldShowDropdown = false
                        selectedOption = option
                        self.onOptionSelected?(option)
                    })
                }
            }, alignment: .topLeading
        )
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).fill(Color.white)
        )
    }
}

struct DropdownSelector_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State private static var address: String = ""
    
    static var uniqueKey: String {
        UUID().uuidString
    }
    
    static let options: [DropdownOption] = [
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Sunday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Monday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Tuesday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Wednesday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Thursday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Friday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Saturday")
    ]
    
    
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            
            HStack(){
                DropdownSelector(
                    placeholder: "Day of the week",
                    options: options,
                    onOptionSelected: { option in
                        print(option)
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .zIndex(1)
                
                DropdownSelector(
                    placeholder: "Day of the week",
                    options: options,
                    onOptionSelected: { option in
                        print(option)
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .zIndex(1)
            }
            
            
            Group {
                TextField("Full Address", text: $address)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 45)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Preview 1]

[image: Preview 2]

You can use the combination of GroupBox and DisclosureGroup to achieve what you're looking for, you can modify below code according to your requirements

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    let nutrients: [String] = ["Energy", "Sugar", "Fat", "Protein", "Vitamins", "Minerals"]
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View{
        GroupBox(){
            DisclosureGroup("Nutritional value per 100g") {
                ForEach(0..<nutrients.count, id: \.self){ index in
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                    
                    HStack{
                        Group{
                            Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                            Text(nutrients[index])
                        }//: GROUP
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.system(.body).bold())
                        
                        Spacer(minLength: 25)
                        
                        Text("1g")
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }//: HSTACK
                }//: LOOP
            }//: DISCLOSURE
        }//: BOX
    }
}

//MARK: - PREVIEW

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

You can customise Toggle with .toggleStyle modifier, first you have to create your style like this

```
struct CheckboxStyle: ToggleStyle {
func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    return HStack{
        //IMAGE
        Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
            .onTapGesture {
                configuration.isOn.toggle()
            }
        
        //LABEL
        configuration.label
    }//: HSTACK
}
}
```

and then apply it on your Toggle like this

```
Toggle("Placeholder label", isOn: .constant(true))
        .toggleStyle(CheckboxStyle())
```

[image: CheckBox]

Comment: It looks everything is fine but the disclosure group has arrow towards right I wanted that to be down and up on selection and unseat

Comment: Found it , Thank you , marking as answer

Comment: I have updated my expected view, Can you suggest how to achieve this ?

Comment: I have added the solution in this answer, you can check it

Comment: @UmairKhan how to get the value selected from disclosure group?

Comment: Set tap gesture on Hstack and get value from array using index